# Linq slow while SQL fast

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

When I'm trying the next linq query, it is slow (1.5 s):

```
var rslt = (from t in context.Set<SUB_Transactions>()
            where
            t.UpdateDate > query.LastUpdate &&
            t.TransactionID > query.Index
            select new
            {
                TransactionID = t.TransactionID
            }).OrderBy(t => t.TransactionID).Take(query.Amount).ToList();
```

When converted to SQL, this query is super fast (40 ms):

```
SELECT TOP (300) 
    [Project1].[TransactionID] AS [TransactionID]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[TransactionID] AS [TransactionID]
        FROM [dbo].[SUB_Transactions] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[UpdateDate] > @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[TransactionID] > @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[TransactionID] ASC
```

What is going on here?

Removing the `Take` in the first query gives a fast result as well (given the fast that there are no new transactions)

There is a composite index on `TransactionID` and `UpdateDate`.

Comment: Question edited. I just do a .ToList().

Comment: Just from a query optimization point of view, you should search on IDs first (assuming that results in the smaller result set) before the date. Date non-equality searches are comparatively time consuming. If the LINQ statement is time consuming, it could because it's calling navigation properties in addition to the query you converted and included in the post

Comment: Can you convert the select part to `select t.TransactionID` so that you don't create an anonymous object for a single property? That'd make it faster to convert once the data is received

Comment: how did you got the converted sql ? Have you captured it using the profiler ? If not then please do so, it is the only way to be sure what sql is actually send to your database

Comment: What is `query`?

Comment: if you can split the query up in parts try `var query = context.Set<SUB_Transactions>().AsQueryable()` and then set the linq things 1 by 1 (eg. query.where(...); repeat) that will optimize the query and it might be a lot faster, also maybe use loadoptions if you have to do a lot with relations (loadwith<>)

Comment: Sorry, I gave a wrong answer moments ago since I forgot the part where you need the ordering at the beginning. But, consider using AsNoTracking() if you need to read the data only and ditch the anonymous object creation.

Comment: What happens if you try putting an extra `.ToList()` clause before the `.Take()`?

Comment: @code4life, that was in a previous, now deleted answer. Generally speaking, it's best to leave SQL do its job in regard to the sorting unless there's a good reason to do otherwise

Comment: I've removed the anonymous object and I've split up the query as @EpicKip suggested without gains.
The AsNoTracking gives no difference either.
I cannot add an extra ToList before the take because it can potentially contains millions of records, for now it contains none. The result is very fast as explained in the OP.
_query_ just contains variables, is irrelevant.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you measured the time in debug vs release? I'm wondering if it's a debugging issue that's taking the time rather than LINQ itself

Comment: @Wouter I'm not sure where to gain speed in the query then, weird that it gives no performance boost

Comment: @DiskJunky The time between them is the same, so not related to debug mode.

Comment: Then it's a very strange one alright. We know we're getting just 300 results back. The optimizations already mentioned should allow LINQ to create a collection of `int`s very quickly and we're not dealing with large numbers nor are they being tracked for changes

Comment: @Wouter did you try with my answer? Specifically my last point in the answer

Comment: Yes, I removed the anonymous type. But the problem is solved (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as your example goes, this could make your query faster but without some sample data it's not possible to test from our end:

```
var rslt = (from t in context.Set<SUB_Transactions>()
            where t.TransactionID > query.Index // invert order of filter
               && t.UpdateDate > query.LastUpdate 
            order by t.TransactionID // you can orderby here
            select t.TransactionID) // remove anonymous object
           .Take(query.Amount)
           .AsNoTracking() // you won't be changing IDs so no need to track them
           .ToList();
```

You might also gain some performance if you used the `DbSet<SUB_Transactions>` instead of calling `Set<SUB_Transactions>()` which needs to locate the `DbSet` in the `DbContext`

Comment: Problem solved. The order of the filter appears to be important for linq, but not for SQL. The other stuff doesn't make a noticeable difference.

Comment: @Wouter You could see the resulting SQL for both and post the differences

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Linq is procedural whereas SQL is declarative with the optimizer doing much of the optimization work. That is why predicate order matters in Linq but not SQL.

Comment: @DanGuzman: true, but you wouldn't be able to gain insight on the extent of the Linq optimization unless you look at the resulting SQL, as Camilo notes.